# Creating all unique combinations (without replacement) of n=2 from a small vector and each value has its corresponding prob in another vec

Tags: r, combinations, probability

I've been browsing for an hour for an answer for my particular problem and haven't found anything. I think the problem is I'm look for a particular issue when a more general tool is capable of doing this.

I read in the data like so:

```
 dat<-as.data.frame(rbind(c(1, .4),
                          c(2, .4),
                          c(3, .1),
                          c(4, .1)))
names(dat)<-c("yi", "del i")
```

I am trying to create a table of all unique combinations of the 2 yi variables and listing the probability of that selection. Is there a prebuilt tool that can do this for me? If not, how could I build a loop within a loop to calculate this? I am having trouble building it myself due to the without replacement aspect part of the problem.

Thanks

edit 1: The final table would look like

```
 sample    prob.     tau    v(tau)
{1,2}     .5333      etc    etc
{1,3}     .1111
{1,4}      etc
.
.
.
{3,4}"
```

edit 2:

```
   P(1,2)=P(getting 1 first n 2 second or getting 2 first and 1 second)
         =P(getting 1 first 2 second) + P(getting 2 first 1 second)
          =(.4)(4/6)+(.4)(4/6)
```

Comment: How are you calculating the probabilities?

Comment: The probabilities are calculated like:


     P(1,2)=P(getting 1 first n 2 second or getting 2 first and 1 second)


             =P(getting 1 first 2 second) + P(getting 2 first 1 second)


              =(.4)(4/6)+(.4)(4/6)

sorry I cannot figure out the formatting for the  comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sampling without replacement is messy. Probably best to just roll your own function for this:

```
combos = combn(dat$yi,2)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    1    1    1    2    2    3
# [2,]    2    3    4    3    4    4

probs = combn(dat$deli,2,function(x) x[1]*x[2]*(1/(1-x[1]) + 1/(1-x[2])) )
# [1] 0.53333333 0.11111111 0.11111111 0.11111111 0.11111111 0.02222222
```

There must be a package for this, but I don't know it.

---

**data.table** You could also take the Cartesian product of `dat` with itself and go from there:

```
library(data.table)

# take Cartesian product and drop diagonal
cart <- setDT(dat)[, c(
  y = CJ(yi,yi,sorted=FALSE), 
  del = CJ(deli,deli,sorted=FALSE))
][y.V1 != y.V2]

# sort values
cart[y.V1 > y.V2, `:=`( y.V1 = y.V2, y.V2 = y.V1)]

# compute probabilities
cart[, sum( del.V1 * del.V2/(1-del.V1) ), by=.(y.V1,y.V2)]
```

which gives

```
   y.V1 y.V2         V1
1:    1    2 0.53333333
2:    1    3 0.11111111
3:    1    4 0.11111111
4:    2    3 0.11111111
5:    2    4 0.11111111
6:    3    4 0.02222222
```

The "sort values" step borrows from [my answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32576421/1191259). Taking the Cartesian product could also be done with [@jangorecki's & Stephanie Locke's `CJ.dt` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27347397/1191259), like `CJ.dt(dat,dat)`.

Comment: I think this problem might lead me towards building a generalized model for this to create as my first package. I very much appreciate the input Frank, I'll let you know if I make progress on creating a generalized model.

Comment: @depizza Cool! I'll be interested to see the result. Looking at the internals of the `sample` function might be a good place to start, since it samples without replacement by default.